# Number with highest frequency in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, counter

I am trying to write a program that will show me the number that appears most frequently in a list. I am trying to do this without importing any libraries. So far I have something that will give me the number of times the most frequent # appears but I want the number itself, not how many times it appears. How can I change what I have so far in a simple way to do this?

```
def freq(L):
    st = []
    L.sort()
    for i in L:
        st.append(L.count(i))
    print max(st)
```

EDIT: for example, freq([4, 6, 4, 3, 9, 1, 4]) is returning 3 since 4 appears 3 times. But I would like it to return 4 as in the most frequent value.

Comment: Potentially float numbers or strictly integers?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` to replace most of the code you've written -- that gives you a dict with the frequency of each item in the list.  Reverse the dict.  Apply `max` to the keys.  Now just use that as the index into the reversed dict.  This will return *one* most-frequent item.

Comment: When you say, "without importing any libraries", does that include modules in the standard library like [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)? If it does, why are you avoiding those libraries? Is this a learning exercise?

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of the input data and what you want the output to be?

Comment: @Prune, Note that `Counter` does have a `most_common` method, which means there's no need to manually calculate the max of your values.

Comment: @jpp: So noted; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try dictionaries

```
def freq(L):
     st = {}
     for i in set(L):
        st.update({L.count(i):i})
     print (st.get(max(st)))
```

or shorter:

```
def freq(L):
    st={L.count(i):i for i in set(L)}
    print (st.get(max(st)))
```

another solution without dictionaries:

```
def freq(L):
    a=0
    b=None
    for e in set(L):
        if L.count(e)>a:
            a=L.count(e)
            b=e
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.count` has O(*n*) complexity, given *n* values in your list. If there are *m* unique values, this means your algorithm will have minimum O(*m* x *n*) complexity. This isn't desirable.

One O(*n*) solution is to create a counting dictionary and increment values as you iterate:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3]

def freq(L):
    d = {}
    for num in L:
        d[num] = d.get(num, 0) + 1
    maxcount = max(d.values())
    return next(k for k, v in d.items() if v == maxcount)

freq(lst)  # 3
```

Of course, with `collections.Counter` the syntax is trivial:

```
from collections import Counter

def freq(L):
    return Counter(L).most_common()[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with list comprehensions:

`mostFrequentNumber = L[max([(L.count(d), i) for i, d in enumerate(L)])[1]]`

To break it down:

We iterate an enumerated version of the list:
`i, d in enumerate(L)`, which will produce tuples with the value and index. Then we create a list of tuples with the `count` of `d` and the index, `i`: `(L.count(d), i)`. We use the Max function to get the one with the highest count. Then we index the list `L` using the highest value at index `[1]` in the tuple.

This input: `L = [1, 1, 1,  2, 3, 4]` will then produce 1 as a result, although may not be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to solve it:

```
from statistics import mode

def freq(L):
    return mode(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using list `st = []` use a dict `dt = {}`.
Also, in your case for performance looping over a `set` is better than going through all *list* elements, `count` method did this for you just loop over a `set` instead.
At the end get index of maximum value of dictionary `dt`:

```py
def freq(L):
    dt = {}
    for i in set(L):
        dt[i] = L.count(i)
    return max(dt, key=lambda k: dt[k])

print(freq([4, 6, 4, 3, 9, 1, 4])) #4
```